# What are the advantages of the general types (int / uint) over specific types (int64 / uint64) in Go lang?

Tags: performance, types, int, go

I understand that `int` and `uint` are 64bit signed / unsigned integers - just like `int64` / `uint64`. And I also understand that `int` is not simply an alias for `int64` (like `byte` -> `uint8` is), so `int64` would need to be converted to `int` and visa versa when applicable. However what are the benefits of using one over the other? Is there any run time performance penalty for using the general types?

Sorry if this is a common question - I had Googled for the answer (and searched on here too) as I'd have thought others might have cropped up before but didn't find anyone answer the question in terms of how they affect performance (if at all), memory usage (I'm guessing not if they're both 64bit integers?) nor how the compiler treats them.

edit: I'm aware that `int` / `unit` are 32bit on 32bit architectures. For the sake of brevity and comparing like for like, I was assuming this is a 64bit Golang environment.

Comment: Performance and memory usage isn't a matter of opinion.

Comment: There exists a sufficiently precise answer to this question that isn't based on a mere opinion. Please vote to reopen the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`int` and `uint` are only 64-bit on 64-bit architectures. On 32-bit architectures they are 32 bits.

The general answer is that, unless you need a certain precision, sticking with datatypes that are the same size as a word on the current architecture (e.g. 32 bits on a 32-bit architecture) is typically slightly more efficient.

Comment: "slightly" is the opposite of an exaggaration. Using a 64 bits type on a 32 bits machine usually results in operations that take at least twice the time than their 32 bits counterparts, often much more because of the increased register pressure.

Comment: I was aware that int is 32bit on 32bit systems (sorry, I should have made that clear in my original post. Sorry about that). So there's no difference in the way how int and int64 are handled on a 64bit system?

Comment: @LaurenceMorgan: Once your code is compiled, there is no difference between `uint` and `uint64` (assuming 64-bit arch). Converting between the two is free. Only the language makes the distinction.

Answer (score 8):

`int` and `uint` correspond to the maximum possible length of basic Go data structures in a Go implementation and runtime. The length of `string`, `map[K]T`, `[]T` and `chan T` always fits into an `int`, and the capacity of `[]T` and `chan T` always fits into an `int`.

An allocation via `make` is bound to return an object with length and capacity that always fit into an `int`. The built-in function `append` returns a slice with length and capacity that never exceed an `int`. The length (the number of defined keys) of a map after inserting a new key-value pair always fits into an `int`.

The main benefit is that *`int` and `uint` are the **smallest** (in terms of bitsize) data types which are safe to use in a Go program in conjunction with common Go data types such as slices and maps.*

The size of `int` is independent from the size of a pointer `*T`. The integer type corresponding to `*T` is `uintptr`. In theory, a Go implementation could choose to map `int` to `int16` - many Go programs would remain to work correctly, but limiting the size of allocations to 15 bits may be too restrictive and would cause runtime panics.

*On 64-bit architectures Go 1.0 has `int` and `uint` 32 bits long, Go 1.1 64 bits long (see [Go 1.1 Release Notes](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.1#int)). This change will increase the memory usage of some Go programs on 64-bit architectures.*.

Explicitly using `int64` instead of `int` in a Go program can make it slower under Go 1.0 and on 32-bit architectures because:

- of conversions between `int` and `int64`
- the performance of certain CPU instructions, such as division, depends on the size of operands

Explicitly using `int64` instead of `int` in a Go program can make it faster under Go 1.0 on 64-bit architectures because:

- The compiler can generate more efficient code for address and offset computation if all operands are 64-bit. Mixing 32-bit and 64-bit operands when computing addresses and offsets is slower.

Using `uint16` as an index when accessing `[1<<16]T` allows the compiler to remove bound checking instructions.

Comment: I've used `uint16` quite effortlessly with maps and slices so the statement that `int` and `uint` are the **smallest** integer types safe to use with maps and slices is not only false but probably the opposite of the truth.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to int being of "native" size slice and array indices are int and not int64 or int32.