# Convert uint64 to int64 without loss of information

Tags: random, go, int64, uint64

The problem with the following code:

```
var x uint64 = 18446744073709551615
var y int64 = int64(x)
```

is that `y` is `-1`. Without loss of information, is the only way to convert between these two number types to use an encoder and decoder?

```
buff bytes.Buffer
Encoder(buff).encode(x)
Decoder(buff).decode(y)
```

Note, I am not attempting a straight numeric conversion in your typical case. I am more concerned with maintaining the statistical properties of a random number generator.

Comment: y is -1? Is your OS a 32bits one, or a 64bits one?

Comment: To the guy that downvoted me, why the downvote? @VonC 64 bit.

Comment: @VonC I'll be. I bet we've set up this Varnish to run as 32 bit!

Comment: What would you want `y` to be if not -1? You want to assert that `x == y` after the conversion and have an error/panic if it is not?

Comment: @ANisus A random number generator returns a discrete set of bits with certain random properties. In this case there are 64 bits of them. I would like to be able to take those 64 bits and use them as an `int64`. I do not want, as I said above, a straight numeric conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing -1 would be consistent with a process running as 32bits.

See for instance the [Go1.1 release notes](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.1#int) (which introduced `uint64`)

```
x := ^uint32(0) // x is 0xffffffff
i := int(x)     // i is -1 on 32-bit systems, 0xffffffff on 64-bit
fmt.Println(i)
```

Using `fmt.Printf("%b\n", y)` can help to see what is going on (see [ANisus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694331/anisus)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911631/6309))

As it turned out, the [OP wheaties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178060/wheaties) confirms ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910696/go-convert-uint64-to-int64-without-loss-of-information/26911142#comment42372921_26911142)) it was run initially in 32 bits (hence this answer), but then realize `18446744073709551615` is `0xffffffffffffffff` (-1) anyway: see [ANisus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694331/anisus)[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911631/6309);

Comment: Running outside of Varnish on a 64 bit machine I'm still seeing it. It's not causing an overflow panic but it is returning `-1` which pretty much destroys all the randomness of the bits.

Comment: @wheaties ok, I was mentioning that possibility after reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/16458451/6309

Comment: I'm kind of at a loss of which one of you two give the answer to. You actually pointed me to the fact that I was running Varnish in a 32 bit set up which would indicate it would always come out -1 while ANisus stated the obvious, I was just drawing the wrong conclusion based upon the experience on the 32 bit system.

Comment: @wheaties I have complete ANisus's answer with an playground example.

Comment: Did the question change? I don't see how this answer has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 16):

Your conversion does not lose any information in the conversion. All the bits will be untouched. It is just that:

```
uint64(18446744073709551615) = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
int64(-1)                    = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Try:

```
var x uint64 = 18446744073709551615 - 3
```

and you will have `y = -4`.

---

For instance: [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1SzPbjMeYH)

```
var x uint64 = 18446744073709551615 - 3
var y int64 = int64(x)
fmt.Printf("%b\n", x)
fmt.Printf("%b or %d\n", y, y)
```

Output:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
-100 or -4
```

Comment: I'm kind of at a loss of which one of you two to give the answer. You correctly pointed out that I was mis-interpreting the -1 to be something it was not. However, that mis-interpritation was a direct result of running Varnish in a 32-bit setting. I think I need to give it to VonC but wish I could give you more +1.

Comment: 18446744073709551615 is 0xffffffffffffffff

Comment: @Anonymous: Thanks for noticing. Added the missing F's

Answer (score 0):

The types uint64 and int64 can both represent 2^64 discrete integer values.

The difference between the two is that uint64 holds only positive integers (0 thru 2^64-1), where as int64 holds both negative and positive integers using 1 bit to hold the sign (-2^63 thru 2^63-1).

As others have said, if your generator is producing `0xffffffffffffffff`, uint64 will represent this as the raw integer (18,446,744,073,709,551,615) whereas int64 will interpret the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) value and return -1.