# What are reasons to use a sized or unsigned integer type in go?

Tags: go

Doing the go tour in chapter "Basics/Basic types" it says:

> When you need an integer value you should use int unless you have a specific reason to use a sized or unsigned integer type.

What are those specific reasons? Can we name them all?

Other available ressources only talk about 32 and 64 bit signed and unsigned types. But why would someone use int types < 32 bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use unsigned values over signed ones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336/when-to-use-unsigned-values-over-signed-ones)

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/golang-nuts/IpzCvzWyYMM/Ga6I2HgDZQsJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of the general types (int / uint) over specific types (int64 / uint64) in Go lang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427416/what-are-the-advantages-of-the-general-types-int-uint-over-specific-types-i)

Comment: If you need to store a million audio samples where each sample range from 0-255, you would waste a lot of memory and possibly speed if you used a 32 bit type to store each sample. That's 1 reason.  I'm sure we can *not* name all the reasons.

Comment: You have 2 separate questions here. For the first, the linked duplicates provide good answers. For the second, it's simply to use less memory.

Comment: A larger type also might not match the _meaning_ you intend for your code. If I'm trying to store a byte or an 0-255 audio sample like @nos mentioned, -1000 or 1000 aren't valid values, and using the narrower type reflects that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you cannot think of a reason not to use a standard `int`, you should use a standard `int`. In most cases, saving memory isn't worth the extra effort and you are probably not going to need to store that large values anyway.

If you are saving a very large number of small values, you might be able to save a lot of memory by changing the datatype to a smaller one, such as `byte`. Storing 8bit values in an `int` means we are storing 24bits of zeroes for every 8 bits of data, and thus, wasting a lot of space. Of course, you could store 4 (or maybe 8) bytes inside an `int` with some bitshift magic, but why do the hard work when you can let the compiler and the cpu do it for you?

If you are trying to do computations that might not fit inside a 32bit integer, you might want an `int64` instead, or even bigint.